# Advice on proper handling, is this wise?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I'm doing some funky stuff with pointers and I'm worried I might be leaving myself open to some pointer problems:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector2
{
private:
 double x;
 double y;

public:
 Vector2(double x, double y)
 {
  this->x = x;
  this->y = y;
 }

 Vector2(double coords[2])
 {
  x = coords[0];
  y = coords[1];
 }

 typedef double * const dArr;
 operator dArr()
 {
  double out[2] = {x, y};
  return out;
 }
};

int main()
{
 double ids[2] = {2.3 ,3.3};
 Vector2 v = ids;
 std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
 double vect[2] = {v[0], v[1]};
 double * const v2 = v;

 std::cout << vect[0] << " " << vect[1] << std::endl;

 while(1) { }

 return 0;
}
```

In the operator dArr() function in my Vector2 class I'm worried that by returning a pointer I am opening myself up to problems where the pointer won't get deleted and it would cause a memory leak. Am I right to be worried, is there a solution to prevent a memory leak in this case? Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: As pointed out in the answers, this isn't a leak, although it is a problem.  However, if you were a leak, you could return some sort of smart pointer.

Comment: @David Thornley: If i were to assign a new pointer to v2 in main() wouldn't the cause the old pointer to be leaked?

Comment: No, the pointer is statically allocated so it will be free'd when it goes out of scope at the end of main. The memory that the pointer points to (which is what you usually leak) is also statically allocated and has already gone out of scope so it is already free'd!

Comment: @Kleist: So it is possible that the pointer v2 would eventually point to a memory address that doesn't contain what I expect? At some point something else may get allocated to that memory location?

Comment: Yes, it probably will at some point. The key is that you can never be certain what will happen so you shouldn't rely on it. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no leak. In general you cannot leak memory if you don't `new` any memory. But you're returning the address of a local variable, which leads to undefined behaviour.

**Solution 1:**
You could use a static double[2] in operator dPtr():

**Solution 2 (Better):**
Store x and y in a double[2] in your class and return a pointer to it instead:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector2
{
private:
   double coords_[2];

public:
   Vector2(double x, double y)
   {
      coords_[0] = x;
      coords_[1] = y;
   }

   Vector2(double coords[2])
   {
      coords_[0] = coords[0];
      coords_[1] = coords[1];
   }

   typedef const double* const dArr;
   operator dArr() const
   {
      return coords_;
   }
};

int main()
{
   double ids[2] = {2.3 ,3.3};
   Vector2 v = ids;
   std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
   double vect[2] = {v[0], v[1]};
   const double * const v2 = v;

   std::cout << vect[0] << " " << vect[1] << std::endl;

   while(1) { }

   return 0;
}
```

I added const in front of `double *` since it is what you point to that is const. (If you don't want the user of your class to fiddle with your private members.)

Answer (score 0):

you have a different problem, your memory will be cleared at the return. but no leaking:P the result should be garbage... the correct way to return such a pointer is indeed new'ed memory or static memory(not a good option, but terribly fast), newed memory might indeed not be deleted, you could return a std::vector instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using a static array container, like `boost::array<double, 2>`. Native arrays have horrendous syntax and semantics- if you want to return an array in that kind of container, you can just return a reference to it like normal.